# How to say this in an idiomatic way when we decide to go to someone's house for a while when we are going past their house?

Tags: idiomatic-language, sentence-request

How can we say this in an idiomatic way?

> When I am going past someone’s house and I stopped at their house and decided to go to their house for a while.

Comment: Drop by, drop in, pop in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say:

> I was in the neighbourhood, and I thought I’d **stop by**.

---

**Stop by**:

> to visit someone for a short time, usually on the way to another place

<sub>Source: Cambridge Dictionary</sub>